# MySQL - Problemas ao alterar a variavel "max_execution_time"

Tags: mysql, odbc, timeout

Tenho um MySQL Server 5.7 instalado em um server Windows, quando altero a variável "max_execution_time" para 6000, quando executo a query abaixo com o ODBC para confirmar se a alteração foi realizada:

**show variables like '%max_execution%';**

O seguinte valor é retornado: 30000

**Queries utilizadas para alterar o valor da variável:**

SET max_execution_time = 60000;

SET GLOBAL max_execution_time = 60000;

SET SESSION max_execution_time = 60000;

Obs: Esse Problema só acontece com o ODBC, porque fiz o mesmo teste com o php e valor retorno foi 60000.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu encontrei uma solução deste caso.
O MySQL ODBC driver 5.3.6 ou posterior não assimila a configuração da variável 'max_execution_time'de servidores MySQL 5.7.4 ou posterior.
Resolvi meu problema fazendo instalando a versão 5.1 do MySQL ODBC driver.